# How can I make zoom, pan scrollView which discriminates pencil from finger touch?

Tags: swift, scrollview

I was trying to make a viewer app, which can swipe page to page and zoomable, can draw with pencil only for each page. To do that, I examined some libraries and test codes, and I found ["Leveraging Touch Input for Drawing apps"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/leveraging_touch_input_for_drawing_apps) test code. I thought that I can utilize this code's logic and tried to remove Main.storyboard and add scrollview to as in this [sample project](https://github.com/bubobubobo/test_viewer). As a novice swift developer I couldn't find why the scrollView, wrapping canvasView(StrokeCGView in sample code) does not zoom in/out while pencil drawing works fine. Could anyout figure out the reason whay the scrollView does not zoom in/out? Here's the root ViewController code... Any comments and references are welcome!! Thank you for reading.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cgView: StrokeCGView!
    
    var pencilStrokeRecognizer: StrokeGestureRecognizer!
    
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    var strokeCollection = StrokeCollection()
    var canvasContainerView: CanvasContainerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        
        let viewFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: screenBounds.width, height: screenBounds.height))
        
        // 2. init StrokeCGView
        let cgView = StrokeCGView(frame: viewFrame)
        self.cgView = cgView
        
        // 3. init canvasContainerView
        let canvasContainerView = CanvasContainerView(canvasSize: cgView.frame.size)
        canvasContainerView.documentView = cgView
        self.canvasContainerView = canvasContainerView
        
        // 1. init scrollView
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: viewFrame)
        
        // 4. update scrollView and add subviews
        scrollView.contentSize = canvasContainerView.frame.size
        scrollView.addSubview(canvasContainerView)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = canvasContainerView.backgroundColor
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [UITouch.TouchType.direct.rawValue as NSNumber]
        scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.allowedTouchTypes = [UITouch.TouchType.direct.rawValue as NSNumber]
        // We put our UI elements on top of the scroll view, so we don't want any of the
        // delay or cancel machinery in place.
        scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false

        self.pencilStrokeRecognizer = setupStrokeGestureRecognizer(isForPencil: true)
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        if #available(iOS 12.1, *) {
            let pencilInteraction = UIPencilInteraction()
            pencilInteraction.delegate = self
            view.addInteraction(pencilInteraction)
        }
        

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    // creates stroke gesture recognizers
    func setupStrokeGestureRecognizer(isForPencil: Bool) -> StrokeGestureRecognizer {
        let recognizer = StrokeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(strokeUpdated(_:)))
        recognizer.delegate = self
        recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        recognizer.coordinateSpaceView = cgView
        recognizer.isForPencil = isForPencil
        return recognizer
    }
    
    func receivedAllUpdatesForStroke(_ stroke: Stroke) {
        print("receivedAllUpdates!")
        cgView.setNeedsDisplay(for: stroke)
        stroke.clearUpdateInfo()
    }

    @objc func strokeUpdated(_ strokeGesture: StrokeGestureRecognizer) {
        print("strokeUpdated!@")
        if strokeGesture === pencilStrokeRecognizer {
            lastSeenPencilInteraction = Date()
        }
        
        var stroke: Stroke?
        if strokeGesture.state != .cancelled {
            stroke = strokeGesture.stroke
            if strokeGesture.state == .began ||
               (strokeGesture.state == .ended && strokeCollection.activeStroke == nil) {
                strokeCollection.activeStroke = stroke
            }
        } else {
            strokeCollection.activeStroke = nil
        }
        
        if let stroke = stroke {
            if strokeGesture.state == .ended {
                if strokeGesture === pencilStrokeRecognizer {
                    // Make sure we get the final stroke update if needed.
                    stroke.receivedAllNeededUpdatesBlock = { [weak self] in
                        self?.receivedAllUpdatesForStroke(stroke)
                    }
                }
               strokeCollection.takeActiveStroke()
            }
        }

        cgView.strokeCollection = strokeCollection
    }
    
    // Timeout the pencil mode if no pencil has been seen for 5 minutes and the app is brought back in foreground.
    let pencilResetInterval = TimeInterval(60.0 * 5)
    
    var lastSeenPencilInteraction: Date? {
        didSet {
            if lastSeenPencilInteraction != nil && !pencilMode {
                pencilMode = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func shouldTimeoutPencilMode() -> Bool {
        print("shouldTimeoutPencileMode!")
        guard let lastSeenPencilInteraction = self.lastSeenPencilInteraction else { return true }
        return abs(lastSeenPencilInteraction.timeIntervalSinceNow) > self.pencilResetInterval
    }
    
    private func setupPencilUI() {
        print("asdf!")
        self.pencilMode = false

        self.willEnterForegroundNotification = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
            object: UIApplication.shared,
            queue: nil) { [unowned self](_) in
                if self.pencilMode && self.shouldTimeoutPencilMode() {
                    // do nothing
                }
        }
    }
    
    var willEnterForegroundNotification: NSObjectProtocol?
    
    var pencilMode = false {
        didSet {
            if pencilMode {
                scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
            } else {
                scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
            }
        }
    }
}


// MARK: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                           shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        print("gestureRecognized!")
        if gestureRecognizer == pencilStrokeRecognizer {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}


// MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        print("viewForZooming!")
        return self.canvasContainerView
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
        print("scrollViewDidEndZooming!")
        var desiredScale = self.traitCollection.displayScale
        let existingScale = cgView.contentScaleFactor
        
        if scale >= 2.0 {
            desiredScale *= 2.0
        }
        
        if abs(desiredScale - existingScale) > 0.000_01 {
            cgView.contentScaleFactor = desiredScale
            cgView.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UIPencilInteractionDelegate
@available(iOS 12.1, *)
extension ViewController: UIPencilInteractionDelegate {

    /// Handles double taps that the user makes on an Apple Pencil.
    /// - Tag: pencilInteractionDidTap
    func pencilInteractionDidTap(_ interaction: UIPencilInteraction) {
        print("doubleTapped!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the delegate setting. Since I removed storyBoard from original project, I had to set delegate inside of viewDidLoad method.

```swift
scrollview.delegate = self
```